# Locus of point satisfying the vector equation $\overrightarrow r \times \overrightarrow a = \overrightarrow b $

Tags: vectors

The minimum distance of origin from the locus of point satisfying the equation $\overrightarrow r  \times \overrightarrow a  = \overrightarrow b $, $\overrightarrow b  \ne 0$ is

(A) $\frac{{\left| {\overrightarrow a .\overrightarrow b } \right|}}{{{a^2}}}$

(B) $\left| {\frac{{\overrightarrow a  + \overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b }}{{{a^2}}}} \right|$

(C) $\left| {\frac{{\overrightarrow a  - \overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b }}{{{a^2}}}} \right|$

(D) $\frac{{\left| {\overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b } \right|}}{{{a^2}}}$

My approach is as follow

$\overrightarrow r  \times \overrightarrow a  = \overrightarrow b  \Rightarrow \overrightarrow a  \times \left( {\overrightarrow r  \times \overrightarrow a } \right) = \overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b  \Rightarrow \left( {\overrightarrow a .\overrightarrow a } \right)\overrightarrow r  - \left( {\overrightarrow a .\overrightarrow r } \right)\overrightarrow a  = \overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b $

How will I proceed from here and what condition I need to use so that the locus of point is minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the fact that $\vec{b}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{r}$. Also, $|\vec{a} \times \vec{r}| = a r \sin\theta_{a,r}$, and therefore, for $\vec{r}$ to be the shortest possible, we should set $\theta_{a,r}=\pi/2$. All in all, all the three vectors are perpendicular and we have $r=b/a$, and (note that $|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}|= ab$) the correct answer is (D).

Answer (score 1):

Break $\vec{r}$ into two components; a multiple of $\vec{a}$ and another vector perpendicular to $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

$$
\vec{r}=m\vec{a}+n\vec{a}\times\vec{b}
$$

Substitute to the initial equation to obtain

$$
n\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\times\vec{a}=\vec{b}\leftrightarrow n=\frac{1}{|a|^{2}}
$$

Finally we have

$$
\vec{r}=m\vec{a}+\frac{1}{|a|^{2}}\vec{a}\times\vec{b}
$$

$|\vec{r}|$ is minimum if $m=0$